# Stimulate rolling dice game

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, dice

I want to write a program that stimulate a game as follows:

> A random number between 1 and 2 is generated to determine which player
> starts the game (player1 or player2).
>
> The player who starts the game will now throw a dice repeatedly adding
> the points scored in each throwing until either the player collects 20
> or more points or until the player gets a 1 point score.
>
> If the player collects 20 or more points, then the score is added to
> the total points of the player and it becomes the other player's turn.
>
> If the player gets a 1 point score before reaching 20 or more points,
> then the player loses his turn without getting any points and it
> becomes the other player's turn.
>
> The other player now starts to play and plays with the same rules as
> described above.
>
> Once the second player ends his turn (either after reaching 20 or more
> points or loses the his turn), then it becomes the first player's turn
> and the game continues.
>
> The first player who reaches a total score of 1000 points wins the
> game.

My program works well, but are there any ways that I can solve the problem by defining only Function `play` without changing its parameters? Can I make Function `turnPoint` be a part of Function `play` without using any loops?

```
import random

def turnPoint(playerTurnPoint):
    if (playerTurnPoint >= 20):
        return playerTurnPoint
    else:
        p = random.randint(1, 6)
        print(p, end = " ")
        if (p == 1):
            return 0
        else:
            playerTurnPoint += p
            return turnPoint(playerTurnPoint)

def play(player1Total, player2Total, currentPlayer):
    if (player1Total >= 1000):
        print("Player 1 won.")
        return None
    elif (player2Total >= 1000):
        print("Player 2 won.")
        return None
    else:
        playerTurnPoint = 0
        if (currentPlayer == 1):
            print("Player 1 playing...")
            print("Points obtained in this turn: ", end = " ")
            playerTurnPoint = turnPoint(0)
            print()
            print("Turn total points = ", playerTurnPoint)
            player1Total += playerTurnPoint
            print("Player 1 total points = ", player1Total)
            play(player1Total, player2Total, 2)
        else:
            print("PLayer 2 playing...")
            print("Points obtained in this turn:", end = " ")
            playerTurnPoint = turnPoint(0)
            print()
            print("Turn total points = ", playerTurnPoint)
            player2Total += playerTurnPoint
            print("Player 2 total points = ", player2Total)
            play(player1Total, player2Total, 1)

#Main Program
player1Total = 0
player2Total = 0
currentPlayer = random.randint(1, 2)
print("Starting the Game")
print("=================")
play(player1Total, player2Total, currentPlayer)
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why are you not happy with function `turnPoint`? Having multiple small functions is usually better than one big function.

Comment: @Stef I know that it is better to have multiple small functions, but is it possible to have one big function?

Comment: Of course it's possible. Just replace each call to `turnPoint` inside `play` by a copy of the whole code of `turnPoint`. But why would you want that? It will only make your code harder to read and understand and maintain.

Comment: If every function is less that, say, 25 lines, and has fewer than, say, 5 variables, and every function has a name that describes what it does, then any programmer can read the code of a function and understand what it does, because each line is easy to understand without too much need for context. But if you start making a huge function with many lines and many variables, then the reader will quickly get lost and have no idea what is happening and to what goal.

Comment: Here your code is already a little hard to read, in part because it's not clear what "turnPoint" means. A more explicit name like `getPointsForCurrentTurn" would make things much clearer, in my opinion.

Comment: Also note that the argument `playerTurnPoint` of `turnPoint` is always 0, except in the recursive calls. For that reason I think it might be better to give it a default value, so that when you call `turnPoint` inside `play`, you don't give it an argument at all.

Comment: This question might be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you! My team leader asked me to do that. I don't know why he made the problem more complicated.

Comment: @Stef I still don't understand about replacing each call to `turnPoint` with the whole code of `turnPoint`. Do I need to include the `def` keyword?

Comment: No. Instead of `playerTurnPoint = turnPoint(0)`, you could write `if playerTurnPoint < 20: p = random.randint(1,6) ...` etc. But this would make your code **worse**, not better.

Comment: @Stef Doing that way, I have to call the recursion of function `play` to calculate the point that the players receive each turn, right?

Comment: Oh, I forgot that `turnPoint` was recursive. Well, if you don't want to use a function for `turnPoint`, then it can't be recursive. You could use a `while`-loop instead. Maybe that's what your team-leader was hinting at? Note that even if you use a `while`-loop, it's better to keep it in a function. There is really no point in making a larger function. Small functions are good.

Comment: @Stef No, he asked me to solve the problem by writing **only** function `play` and without using any loops.

Comment: Well, then the logic would be different enough that you'd be better off rewriting the whole code from scratch, rather than trying to modify the code you've already written. I guess he wants you to make recursive calls in `play`.

Comment: @Stef Ok, but it seems complicated by doing that.